# result[0] is recognized as undefined

Tags: javascript

So this function uses fetch to get a list of team names and pass them on to the getTeams() function

```
export function process_all_teams(func) {
    fetch('/teams')
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((result) => {
        return getTeams(result);
    })
    .then((results) => {
        js_avg_goals(results);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
}
```

The getTeams function then uses the names to retrieve the list of players from the /teams/<team_name> url to create and return an array of js Team objects.

```
function getTeams(result){ 
    let promises = Array(12);
    for(let i=0; i < result.length; i++){
        let url = '/teams/' + result[i];
        promises[i] = fetch(url).then((response) => {return response.json()});
    }

    let teams  = Array(12);
    Promise.all(promises)
    .then((res) => {
        for(let i=0; i < res.length; i++){
            teams[i] = new Team(res[i]);
        }
    })
    .catch(() => console.log("There was an error in getTeams"))

    return teams;
}
```

In the js_avg_goals function I'm trying to log out results[0] but it returns 'undefined' while results returns the actual array of Team objects.

```
export function js_avg_goals(results) {
    console.log(results);
    console.log(results[0]);
}
```

This is the Team constructor. The first item of the array res is the team name while the rest are players that are represented as player objects converted to json.

```
function Team(res){
    this.name = res[0];
    this.players = res.slice(-15);
}
```

I don't understand why this is happening somebody please help me.

Comment: What does `/tems` return, in plain text?

Comment: Put `console.log(result)` at the beginning of `getTeams` to see what the result is.

Comment: @Siguza /teams returns a list of team names. It is converted to json from the python backend file

Comment: @Barmar It returned an array of strings, which are the team names

Comment: `return teams;` is outside the `Promise.all()`, so it's not waiting for the promises to be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Promise.all` returns a new promise.

Modify `getTeams` to return that promise, something like this:

```
return Promise.all(promises)
    .then(res => res.map(r => new Team(r)))
    .catch(() => console.log("There was an error in getTeams"))
```